# Basic questions on regular/recursive expressions (discrete maths)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

there. I have an assignment coming up and was wondering if you could assist me? I was having trouble using asterisks on here as they are used for Bold, I think, so I replaced them with an apostrophe '.

"Construct a regular expression that defines the language M (say) containing all words with either exactly one single a-substring or all words with only ab-substrings."

I answered with M = {b'ab' + (ab)'}.

The first part contains the single a and has b's before and after.
The plus indicates an OR.
The (ab)' indicates a number of ab substrings.

"Construct a regular expression that defines the language N (say) containing all words of odd length ending in a b"

This one I'm unsure of, as I don't really know how to represent the odd length.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* One way to represent the language on $2$ letters containing all even length words is
$$\left((a+b)^2\right)^*$$

Comment: Ah, thank you. But with (a + b)^2, can I get an answer where the 2 elements differ? For example, ab or ba.

Comment: @Boom Yes, $(a+b)^2=aa+ab+ba+bb$.